# How to represent a check valve in simulink?

Tags: controls, simulink

i am a new simulink user, how to represent a check valve in simulink?I am using version 2012b.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the SimHydraulics toolbox then it is as simple as making use of the [Check Valve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/hydro/ref/checkvalve.html) block.

If you are not already familiar with this toolbox, [SimHydraulics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/hydro/ug/product-description.html) is an extension of the [Simscape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/gs/product-description.html) toolbox.  Simscape can be useful when you are doing physical modeling such as this, as it provides a library of physical components that can be connected in the same structure as whatever the real-life system is.  This differs somewhat from a "standard" Simulink model which is more of a block diagram that typically represents the actual mathematical equations that describe the underlying dynamics of your system.

With that said, if you don't have Simscape and need to model this using base Simulink blocks, then you will need to first figure out what is the underlying logic/equations that would describe your check valve.